# Where are consolidated TestNG reports present for publishing to CI?

Tags: jenkins, testng, integration-testing

`target/surefire-reports/TEST*.xml`, and

`target/surefire-reports/junitreports/TEST*.xml`

Above files only have the re-run tests from `testng-failed.xml`.
But I need complete test results to be published in Jenkins, the successful cases and failed cases, all.

Need a solution that does not needs code changes like implementing listeners etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should find a `testng-results.xml` file somewhere in `target/**` which is what you are looking for.

It is recommended to use [the TestNG Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin) too.